# How do I understand Labels & Codes [ C or U ] in Cambridge dictionary correctly?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

in Cambridge dictionary, [C] refers to

> Countable noun: a noun that has a plural

[U] refers to

> Uncountable or singular noun: a noun that has no plural.

What does [ C or U ] mean? Take this (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dinner) as our running example.

> [image: snippet of dinner entry]

I guess that means this word could be used as Countable or Uncountable and depends on the context. However, I didn't see that in the examples in the first section.

> [image: the definitions of "dinner"]

In AMERICAN DICTIONARY section, there are indeed examples marked [ U ], all of them!

> [image: the AmEng definition of "dinner"]

How do I understand [ C or U ] here correctly?

Comment: Do you understand what A1 refers to? For those who don't, it refers to the language level it represents. A1 describes the language proficiency [according to the CEFR benchmarks](https://www.coe.int/en/web/common-european-framework-reference-languages), these words are among the easiest in the English language, the most frequently used, and normally the first words a learners studies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.

Many uncountable nouns can also be used as countable when a particular instance is being referred to (eg *injustice*, *truth*).

But that doesn't seem to apply here: *dinner* (like other meals) is usually uncountable even when it refers to a particular occasion:

> They came over for dinner.
>
> I'll do it after dinner.
>
> I always studied after dinner.

But there are a few cases where it can be used as a countable noun. One is when talking about catering for a particular (or vague) number of people:

> We've served seventy breakfasts and fifty-nine dinners today.

All the other cases I can think of are talking about particular instances, but are often optional:

> During my stay, I got my dinner/dinners at The Kings Head.

I think "dinner" (uncountable) is more common here, but "dinners" is possible, treating them as separate events.

**Edit**: one particular case which is always plural (and hence countable) is the idiomatic exclamation: *... more [something] than you've had hot dinners!*

Another is when a particular event is further qualified, as in *a candlelit dinner* above.

Note: I am ignoring the different meaning of *dinner*, as a formal dining event, usually with speeches. This is always countable.

Comment: Someone might boast "He's had more girlfriends than **hot dinners**"

Comment: You're right, @Mari-LouA, and I thought I had mentioned that idiom; but I must have taken it out.

Comment: By all means include the idiom, it's a handy one for learners to study.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I've added it. But I've remembered why I took it out: the common case is where there is a different subject, but "had" is expressed, giving a rather difficult parse.

Answer (score 0):

- [C] - Countable noun

Countable nouns are those nouns which you can count, i.e.: book, pen, coin.

- [U] - Uncountable noun

Uncountable nouns cannot be counted, i.e.: money, flour, water.

Answer (score 0):

*Countable* (according to a [different, clearer dictionary](http://english.oxforddictionaries.com/countable)) means:

> (of a noun) that can form a plural **or be used with the indefinite article.**

Therefore, there is a count example:

> **a** romantic candlelit dinner

And the other two are non count. Cambridge just doesn’t mark each individual example for whatever reason.

Answer (score 0):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dinner) explains the noun **dinner** as:

**the main meal of the day** and it says that it can be used either as a countable or uncountable noun [C or U], depending on the context. What confuses you is that they didn't mark all three examples they provide separately as [C] or [U], but it is obvious which is which, because a countable noun in singular comes with an indefinite article (a dinner).

- *We were just having (our) dinner.* Here, "dinner" is used as an uncountable noun (without "a")
- *a romantic candlelit dinner* Here, a dinner is used as a countable noun (with "a").

Comment: This answer simply restates the question, and adds a second definition which was not relevant to the question (because, as you say, that meaning is always countable). It makes no attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @ColinFine, the OP is confused about the mark [C or U], which is only at the top of the section with three sentences, but not next to each sentence provided. I'm explaining that this means that you can use "dinner" as a countable or uncountable noun - as you prefer, so it's not a predetermined thing.